# How does Shia interpret Muhammad b. al-Hanafiyyah hadith about which of the people is the best after the Messanger?

Tags: shiism, shia-sunni

Muhammad b. al-Hanafiyyah was a son of Ali ibn Abi Talib, in a Sahih hadith he mentioned:

> I said to my father: Which of the people after the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) is best? He replied: Abu Bakr. I then asked: Who comes next? He said: ‘Umar. I was then afraid of asking him who came next, and he might mention ‘Uthman, so I said: You came next, O my father? He said: I am only a man among the Muslims.

I find this hadith contradicting to the fundamental values of Shia beliefs, not only the view of Umar to be one of the best people after the prophet, but that they are even mentioned before Ahl al-Kisa for example. How does Shia Muslims interpret this hadith?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Do not use comments to answer questions. They need to be posted as an answer that can be properly voted on.